# Rails routes with polymorphic and owner relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-routing

I have a rails app where `Users` can create `Programs` and other things yet to come, we'll say `Plans` (hypothetically).

`Users` can also `like` `Programs` and `Plans`. (Like is polymorphic)

I am trying to figure out routes so I can see the `Programs` a `User` creates, all the things a `User` `likes`, or just `Programs` or just `Plans` a `User` `likes`. 
I have these routes, but this doesn't seem to be right.

```
resources :users, :only => [:index,:show] do
    resources :programs, :only => [:index]
    resources :likes, :only => [:index] do
        resources :programs, :only => [:index]
    end
end
```

The route for `programs` that a `user` `likes` requires a URL like: users/user_id/likes/like_id/program.

How do I create a URL like: users/user_id/likes/programs and get all programs that are liked.

I am using the [Socialization Gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) which has a method for "likeables_relation(Class)" which returns a relation of whatever class is requested. I just need help with the routing.

Comment: What do your models look like, and you you using a Has Many Belongs to  Many polymorphic Relationship right? You might end up just having to declare the route the old fashion way, because a Has many Belongs To Many polymorphic isn't standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried with the following routes:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index,:show] do
  resources :programs, :only => [:index]
  resources :likes, :only => [:index] do
    collection do
      get :programs
    end
  end
end
```

and the

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/likes/programs
```

works fine.

It required adding a new action 'programs' to the LikesController class.

This is what rake routes returns:

```
programs_user_likes GET /users/:user_id/likes/programs(.:format) likes#programs
```